# Defining a Firestore query by comparing two document's fields values

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm having my first steps with Cloud Firestore, and I am stuck on this one.
I'm looking for a where query to return me values that are `>=` the limit.

```
  [{
    'limit': 100,
    'value': 200 
  }, 
  {
    'limit': 50,
    'value: 50,
  },
  {
    'limit': 95,
    'value': 90, 
  }]
```

I am using the Firebase Admin Python SDK in a Cloud Function.

Any hints?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and is it for Android, iOS or web?

Comment: That is the whole structure (example data) - just two fields - limit and value. It's for python ( google cloud function )

Comment: I cannot see any collection/documents schema there, that's why I have asked you for a screenshot.

Comment: That's the collection - let's call it 'checks', check is a document with fields 'limit' and 'value'. I want to retrieve all documents having value greater or equal the limit.

Comment: That's not a Firestore schema. So help me, so I can help you.

Comment: Ok I get it, key can be ignored for this purpose, if that's what making the confusion. Screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o92mr77i9fdb0s/Screenshot%202019-10-07%2014.24.21.png?dl=0

Comment: I just need the documents where 'limit' is <= 'value' .   ( doesn't have to do anything with the 'limit' keyword if there is such in firestore )

Comment: And the `value` is set by you, right?

Comment: In your case, for example you want to get all documents that have the limit `>=` 60 and the result should be two documents, the first and the third, right?

Comment: no, I want to use 'limit' in the where query. Let's call limit=a and value=b if that makes it easier, I guess I shouldn't have used keywords in example. So all I want is all the documents where b>a.  in this case it's first and second .

Comment: The last question, you want to get all documents where the value of the `limit` property is `>=` than the value of `value` property.  In your example, the result shoud be a single document, the last once, since `95 >= 90`, right?

Comment: Whichever way really... but let's do all documents that value property is >= than value of value property so first two.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand your last sentence. Was I  right with what you want in my last comment?

Comment: I don't know mate how many times I can write that all over again the same, I'm starting to worry I'll get banned on SO because of too many comments ;)  Whichever way the comparison <= or >= , doesn't matter, but to keep with my question and answers - all the documents where 'value' is >= 'limit', so first two.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alex has explained, there is no way to compare two document's fields values when executing a query with Firestore.

One possible approach, would be to save the result of the inequality when you save the document to the database. If, when you save a "check" document you know the two values (`limit` and `value`), you could add a third field named, for instance,`valueAboveLimit` with a value of `True` or `False`, that you calculate when you save the "check" document (i.e. from your front-end with the corresponding client SDK or from a server with the Firebase Admin Python SDK, depending on how you write the Firestore documents).

Then your query will be easy:

```
database = firestore.client()
col_checks = database.collection('checks')
query_checks = col_checks.where('valueAboveLimit', '==', True)
results = query_checks.get()
```

---

In case you don't have the values of `limit` and `value` at the time you save the Firestore document (for example the `limit` field is written later), you could use a Cloud Function that is triggered [when the Firestore document is changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentBuilder?authuser=0#onUpdate) and, if the two fields are present, calculates and saves this `valueAboveLimit` field.

Comment: Vey nice approach Renaud! 

Comment: Thanks Alex, thanks Renaud - "there is no way to compare two document's fields values when executing a query with Firestore" - that's all I wanted to confirm. I can solve my problem client side, but thanks Renuad !

Answer (score 1):

According to the earlier comments, you are looking for a way in which you can query the database so it can return only the documents where the value of `limit` property is `>=` than the value of `value` property. So according to you example, the expected result should be the first and the second document.

Unfortunately, there is currently no built-in query in Firestore that can help you achieve that. The simplest solution I can think of, would be to get all documents within your `checks` collection and filter the results client side. If you have in your collection a large number of documents, this might not be the best solution since it require to read all documents. This means that you be billed with one read operation for every document you read.

Another solution, might be to use a fiexed value for the `limit` property and query the database using a `where()` call:

```
col_checks.where('limit', '>=', your_limit)
```

And every time you need a new limit, you'll have to create a new query.